# CICD pipeline fails with InterpolationSyntaxError

Tags: python

Im trying to run the CICD pipelines. but my python code which is suppose to get the parameters from the azure data factory fails with the error `configparser.InterpolationSyntaxError: '%' must be followed by '%' or '(',`. I understand the error but possible thing that can fix does not really seem to work.

this is my code snippet

```
    f = open(parametersJson,)
    # returns JSON object as dict
    data = json.load(f)
    # Iterating through the json
    parametersJsonDict = {}
    for key,value in data['parameters'].items():
        value = value.replace('%','%%')
        parametersJsonDict[key]=value["value"]

    f.close()
    parametersIniDict = {}
    argumentStringDict = {}
    for env in envs:
        parametersIniDict[env] = {}
        config = configparser.ConfigParser()
        config.optionxform = str
        config.read(parametersIni)
        argumentStringDict[env] = ""
        for key, value in config[env].items():
            value= repr(value)
            parametersIniDict[env][key]=value
            try:
                value = json.loads(value)
            except:
                pass
            if isinstance(value, Mapping) or isinstance(value, list):
                argumentStringDict[env] = argumentStringDict[env] +" -" + str(key) + " " + json.dumps(value)
            else:
                argumentStringDict[env] = argumentStringDict[env] +" -" + str(key) + " \"" + str(value) + "\""
    
    
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.optionxform = str
    
    failBuildMessage = []
    failBuild="false"
    
    for env in envs:
        config[env] = {}
        addIniDict = {}
        removeIniDict = {}
        for key,value in parametersJsonDict.items():
            if key in parametersIniDict[env]:
                config[env][str(key)] = str(parametersIniDict[env][key])
            else:
                addIniDict[key] = str(value)
        for key,value in parametersIniDict[env].items():
            if not key in parametersJsonDict:
                removeIniDict[key] = str(value)
                
        if len(addIniDict)>0:
            failBuild ="true"
            failBuildMessage.append(f"There are some overwrite parameters that need to be added in {env}, check the test artifacts")
            config[env+'_add'] = {}
            for key,value in addIniDict.items():
                config[env+'_add'][str(key)] = f'"{str(value)}"'
    
        if len(removeIniDict)>0:
            failBuild ="true"
            failBuildMessage.append(f"There are some overwrite parameters that need to be removed in {env}, check the test artifacts")
            config[env+'_remove'] = {}
            for key,value in removeIniDict.items():
                config[env+'_remove'][str(key)] = f'"{str(value)}"'
```

I tried added this line  `value= repr(value)` to conver the varibale into raw string but did not work,

I also tried this line `value=value.repalce("%","%%"). still did not work.

Important to mention:  First time I got the error I added to my code this line ``value=value.repalce("%","%%")` I re run the pipeline and it worked. but failed to the point where it neeeds to produce overwrite parametes from ADF.

When this failes normally it produces the artifact with the parameters that I need to copy and paste in my config file. I could see that my paramters already where having `%%` instead of single '%'. After adding this to config file. I re run the pipeline to but it still failed as running as a first time, reffering to `InterpolationSyntaxError`.

Anyone could help?

FULL traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/agent/_work/2/s/CICD/pipelines/scripts/adf_overwrite_parameter_check.py", line 42, in <module>
    for key, value in config[env].items():
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/_collections_abc.py", line 744, in __iter__
    yield (key, self._mapping[key])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/configparser.py", line 1234, in __getitem__
    return self._parser.get(self._name, key)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/configparser.py", line 800, in get
    d)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/configparser.py", line 394, in before_get
    self._interpolate_some(parser, option, L, value, section, defaults, 1)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/configparser.py", line 444, in _interpolate_some
    "found: %r" % (rest,))
configparser.InterpolationSyntaxError: '%' must be followed by '%' or '(', found: '%27/sites/U-Uitgevers/Gedeelde%20documenten/Business%20plannen/MJP%20(nieuwe%20fondsstructuur%20en%20uniform%20format)/Power%20BI%20-%20Mapping/mapping%20tabel%20met%20business%20logica.xlsx%27)/$value"'
```

line 42 refers to this line         `argumentStringDict[env] = "" for key, value in config[env].items():`

Comment: Can you reduce your code to a [mre]?

Comment: if I do so nobody will understand where the issue could come from but I already fixed this and post the answer myself

Answer (score 0):

I have repalced this line

`config = configparser.ConfigParser()`

with this line

`config = configparser.ConfigParser(interpolation=None)`